# PHP / MYSQL list rows by month and year

Tags: php, mysql, date

I made an events system with php and mysql, i add the event in the database with the following fields: id, title, content, date (timestamp : YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00)

I want to sort mysql records by year/month and count results

*Example :*

**JANUARY 2012 : 3 results**

- Event1 title1 content1 date1
- Event2 title2 content2 date2
- Event2 title2 content2 date2

**DECEMBER 2011 : 2 results**

- Event1 title1 content1 date1
- Event2 title2 content2 date2

...

I try differents ways using group by but nothing conclusive
I appreciate your time and i wait for feedback. Thanks in advance.

I tried this code

```
SELECT id, title, content, date, EXTRACT( YEAR
FROM date ) ANNEE, EXTRACT( 
MONTH FROM date ) MOIS, COUNT(*) AS mySum
FROM plaquerecherchee
GROUP BY ANNEE, MOIS
ORDER BY ANNEE, MOIS
```

but i have only one result for one month...

Comment: are you using `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY`- please add the current query you are trying to your quesion

Comment: Code added in the question thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
select Event1, title1, content1, MONTH(date),count(1) from yourtable
group by  Event1, title1, content1, MONTH(date)
```

Comment: I tried the code, see as added in my question, but i obtain only one result. I wanted to list all the entries

JANUARY 2012 : 3 results

    Event1 title1 content1 date1
    Event2 title2 content2 date2
    Event2 title2 content2 date2

DECEMBER 2011 : 2 results

    Event1 title1 content1 date1
    Event2 title2 content2 date2

Comment: Are you sure that you have all the data there? And second the exact output as you want it would require a bit different way of solving the problem. like CASE WHEN ... THEN select '... '.

Comment: With my code, i obtain the entry with the last timestamp for each month.

Example
date,ANNEE,MOIS,mySum
2011-10-29 18:00:00,2011,10,208
2011-11-30 23:00:00,2011,11,180

I wanted to have the 208 listed entries for october and the 180 entries for november.

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: The group by and count() will give you an aggregated result of all of your records and their counted result. You will not be able to see a list of ALL your records using them. I'll write another one if that's what you want

Comment: If you have an idea, yes it would be very useful for me.I appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,title,content,date,count(*) as mySum from TABLENAME
GROUP BY date.MONTH, date.YEAR
ORDER BY date.YEAR,date.MONTH
```